# Maximum application size of android & BADA platform

Tags: android, client, size, bada

what is maximum  size of thick/thin client application(to d/w through OTA) in both Android & Samsung Bada platform ?

Comment: I want to know the size for Samsung Bada platform. Any help is highly appreciated. Started a bounty.

Answer (score 3):

yokks, you need to have a look @ this thread [Android - Application (apk) Maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size) for android

Comment: thankyou surabh. that's the perfect one to test the application size.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Android Market by "OTA" which is the most common case since it handles update notifications, etc. - you should know that the apk size limit to upload on the android market is 25 MB. But other than that, I don't know of any limitation, it probably also depends on the device you're targeting.

If you implement your own OTA delivery technique, then of course you don't have this limitation.
Also you should know that on Android you can always/mostly break down one application into multiple smaller ones, if your app elements are very modular, in case you have issues with one single apk size.