# install large APK on Android device

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Application (apk) Maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size)

I want to install an APK file with 350 MB size in Android real devices.

- Is this possible?
- What is the maximum size of an APK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According this thread http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4250 
you need 1400MB available on a real devices to install a APK file with 350MB. Most developer use external storage to store big data, including me.

The maximum size is about 24MB on Android Market.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a database?  Other files that need to be used?

Try storing your extra data on the SD card under the /data/[your.app.package.name].