# What is the maximum Android Application size?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - Application (apk) Maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size)

I have an app that will have lots of videos.  The iPhone version is 1.2GB.  I am converting it to Android and would like to know if 1.2GB is too big?  Is there an Android like iTunes application that a user can purchase apps and sync with their Android phone?

I am not a big fan of putting the video files on a server and have the app download the media files to the sdcard. Not that it can't be done but these videos are 10+ Mb and there are over 100 files.

Comment: See a similar post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2010, it is [50MB](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-market-client-update.html). If you want to distribute a 1.2GB APK, the only way to do that is outside of the market. Users on most Android phones can install non-market apps if they change a setting... but you aren't going to get much exposure.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be a fan of the app downloading the videos, but what's the real penalty? The user is going to have to download the data one way or another. At least if the app is doing it, it can go on in the background. That way the user experience is that the app is quick to download and start, with (unsurprising) delays every once in a while when trying to view a video that hasn't been downloaded in the background yet.

Answer (score 0):

Previously it was 50MB, [but on September 28, 2015, Google increased it to 100MB](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html). For larger than 100MB apps, you can consider using [expansion files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)

**Related (Dec 07, 2016): [Saving Data: Reducing the size of App Updates by 65%](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html)**