# shall i do android tablet version project in same or as different project?

Tags: android

We have developed an app in medium(320x480) and high (480x800) supporting portrait and landscape. App has so many images so the build apk file size is 27 MB up to now.

Now client wants app in tablet version. If i do tablet version in the same project i think app size will be reach to more than 30MB.

Is there any problem if the app size reaches more than 30MB ?

Shall i do this tablet version in the same project or in different project. Please suggest me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application may not work as expected on Tablet if

1) you have used Android APIs that have been deprecated in HoneyComb version (Android version for Tablet). This begs using new APIs, worst case redesign.

2) you have tailormade UI widget for 320x480. This could include hardcoded resolution values, small resolution images used in UI widgets. In this case you need to redesign your UI Screen and fine tune it for Tablet.

3) your workspace in Froyo /Gingerbread. You need to migrate your application workspace to HoneyComb.

4) your app has put any limitation because of hardware. This I derived from the fact that your current app has been developed for 320x480 resolution, must be a slow hardware. But Tablet are powered by 1 - 1.5 GHz processors. You may need to have a look at new set of limitation (or freedom ?). For example memory limit on application may have gone up.

In short I would suggest have a different workspace for Tablet, however if your application has classes that are independent of above stuff, then you can share your package across application. (Tablet Vs Phone App).

Shash

Comment: Hi Shash, do u have any ref link that i can show to client... Thank you

Comment: Not as of now, if I find any, I ll let you know

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any problem if the app size reaches more than 30MB ?

If you are planing to upload your application  to android market there is a file size limit of 50MB for an apk file. Other problems related to large apk files are listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size) SO question

Update:
Google updated their market policies you may refer this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html)