# List of Android phones and the max app memory sizes?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a list of Android phones and their respective maximum app memory sizes. Also how do you prevent someone from downloading your app if their phone doesn't allow you enough memory to run?

I want to keep 12-18mb in memory, but can do 3mb if I completely change the way the user interacts with the data. I just don't have the information I need to make that decision.

EDIT - I'm looking for the maximum amount of memory an app can use per phone.  ie What percentage of phones out there will be able to load my app if it needs 18mb of memory. Since this is so fundamental I'm wondering if my English is failing me in my online search. I have 2 phones purchased last year that have 256mb, but an app taking up 18mb of memory will be terminated on both.

EDIT2 - This is surely my English, but there is a difference between how much memory the phone has, how big your apk can be and how much memory your app can take up while running. I am looking for the last. It is different for different phones yet:

A) There is no way to know without trying and crashing whether some random person can run your app

B) How many phones out there can run my app if it takes up 20MB of memory while running.

Comment: List of Android [Phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices). and For Max app [memory sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size/3536527#3536527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark,

I don't think your English is failing you. You are very well spoken and articulate well what you are looking for. Keep it up! That said, on to your topic:

The issue you are having finding this information is because there is not a standard source, nor a standard of implementation. Each manufacturer has modified the source and set their limitations according to what they believe will fit the bill. The best resource for this information is to speak with the ROM hackers who compile this information. Their list is not guaranteed to be complete, nor completely accurate, but they are rarely far from the mark.

The first place I would start is [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/). They have a great forum with a lot of technical information and a lot of device support. If they don't have a list, someone on that site will know where or how to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The information below is from an email I received from HTC responding to an email I sent them asking which phones had the largest memory for apps. They responded listing phones from most app memory to least that could be used on a GSM network such as Tmobile or ATT:

1. Amaze- 1 GB RAM, 16 GB ROM (within this you will likely have access to somewhere between 750 MB and 600 MB of app storage out of the box).
2. HD7- 512 MB RAM, 16 GB (non-removable microSD™) ROM
3. MyTouch 4G Slide- 768 MB RAM, 4 GB internal storage
4. Sensation- 768 MB RAM, 4 GB internal storage