# How much space does the Qt for Android take up?

Tags: android, qt, apk

I just read this question about packaging for Android:

[Android - Application (apk) Maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size)

Where it mentions that apk files have a maximum size for the market place:

http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469

When using the Qt for Android:

http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/

How much space does that take up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include the `Qt` libraries in your application so the space of the app depends only on the application itself.

The guy behind [`necessitas`](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/) has also created [`ministro`](https://market.android.com/details?id=eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro) which fetches the `Qt` libraries required by your application.

> Ministro is a system wide Qt shared libraries installer/provider
>   service. It acts as a bridge between your apps and Qt libraries.
>
> Ministro service is release under GPL v3+ license.

Have a look at this [QuickStart video] which demonstrates the process of writing/installing a `Qt` Application in `Android`

**EDIT**

Of course if you want you can select to use [deploy local qt libs](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/wiki/How%20to%20write%20Qt%20apps%20for%20Android/attachment/qtCreator_deployConfiguration.png) with your application instead of the device libs. In this case the extra space required depends on the `Qt` modules you use.