# Can we place folder(images) containing 40mb in assets folder in android?

Tags: android

I need to **display images** in my project from **local sqlite database** and so I kept them in **assets** folder. The size of the images folder is **40mb**. Since my project contains lot many images I have chosen assets folder instead of drawable folder. But when I kept the 40mb size folder in assets my emulator is showing error and my app is not running.

**In Console:**

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2011-12-09 11:47:16 - Mccee] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-12-09 11:47:16 - Mccee] Launch canceled!
```

**In Logcat**

```
12-09 11:44:03.210: WARN/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(89): setKernelCountSet(10041, 0) failed with errno -2
12-09 11:44:03.220: WARN/InputManagerService(89): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@414013c0 (uid=10041 pid=1049)
12-09 11:44:03.340: WARN/ActivityManager(89): Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord{413ba658 com.android.myproject/.Select}
12-09 11:44:05.840: WARN/ThrottleService(89): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

What could be the reason. I have searched in google and tried many links...like keeping    -partition-size 1024 in default emulator options but didnt worked. Also I have created new emulator with 1GB size but even then it didnt worked. Could you please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: You must check this answer first: [Android - Application(APK) Maximum size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7346935/379693)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can place a folder of size 40MB in your asset folder, The error of emulator is for not sufficient internal size of emulator, try your application on device. Also If your application is large sized advice you to if possible save your application on SDcard.