# Can we store 30mb of data in our android application?

Tags: android

Actually my project database size is **30mb**. I have used only **7mb** of data till now. But now **I need to place the complete database(30mb) in my assets folder** of my project. **Can we place that much data for android application?** Please help me regarding this. 
   Will be thankful to you

Comment: Do note that users do not like to install large applications. If there's any other way to reach this data, as in for example over HTTP, you should consider it.

Answer (score 1):

An apk has a max size of 50mb, so it should be ok. Here is a related question: [Android - Application (apk) Maximum size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536463/android-application-apk-maximum-size)

Edit: And of course this is only for the Android market, I don't know if there is any other limits. However, 30mb should never be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on internal memory of your phone. Because all files from assetes are get written in internal memory/ external if you installing app on memory card. But for installation app will take to much time.