# Can the apk file exceed 50mb size in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android applications. **Currently my apk size is 12mb.** I need to keep 40mb size images in my project. So if I keep those images in my drawable folder then my apk size will exceed 50 mb. **So will the apk install in mobile if it exceeds 50 mb?** Please help me regarding this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please take a look at [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3536463/940096) helps you.!!!

Comment: Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html). But please put some effort before asking questions here..

Comment: Your question sounds like you are asking if you can install a file larger than 50MB on a device, try and put a large asset file (greater than 50mb) into your assets folder and push it to a device. If you are asking wether Google Play can support apps larger than 50MB then teh answer is what Rajesh put - Apk Expansion Files

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install your apk directly on sdcard then you can go for `installLocation`(without publishing apk)

or else use *Expansion file* concept of Android, while publishing your apk you can attach(main|patch) file.

*main*: Primary resource(application cant run without it)

*patch*: secondary resource(application can tun without it)

All you need is to collect your content and make a zip, should follow naming format as below

```
<main|patch>.expansioncode.packagename ".obb" implicitly append why Google.
```

You have to do Licencing even your app is free. 
you must have **public key** of merchant account.

how to download Expansion Content you can find here
http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

While downloading you have to pass parameter content size(in byte) to map the file

```
XAPKFile(boolean isMain, int fileVersion, long fileSize)
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html#Download

Answer (score 0):

**As of recently** (Sept. 2015)**, you are able to upload APKs up to 100 MB** if you are targeting Android 2.3 and above - you can read more about it [on this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB). This limit was previously 50 MB. There is also the Android developers blogspot article explaining the changes [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/support-for-100mb-apks-on-google-play.html).

Alternatively, or if your app exceeds the 100 MB APK limit, you can use **expansion files**. These are additional files that are downloaded after your app has installed and can be up to 4 GB (to be specific, you can have two expansion files of up to 2 GB each). You can learn more about expansion files on [this page on the Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).